# How can I specify a function in Minizinc that returns True if a boolean array contains at least one True element, and False otherwise?

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, solver, minizinc, satisfiability

## The problem

In a Minizinc model where I want to minimize a linear cost function, I can say the following:

```
set of int: foos = 1..8;
set of int: bars = 1..5;

array[foos] of float: cost;
array[foos, bars] of var bool: assignment;

solve minimize sum(foo in foos) (
  sum(bar in bars) (cost[foo] * assignment[foo, bar])
);
```

What I want to do is to specify a nonlinear/discrete function like this:

```
solve minimize sum(foo in foos) (
  any_fun(bar in bars) (assignment[foo, bar])
);
```

where `any_fun` returns True if one or more elements in array `assignment[foo, :]` is True, like `np.any(x)` in Numpy.

So if my `assignment` matrix is as follows:

```
[[False, False], [True, False], [True, True]]
```

then applying `any_fun` on each row returns `False`, `True`, `True` respectively.

However, I can't seem to find a function that resembles `any_fun`. Is there a way to implement this?

## What I tried

I tried the following. This seems to work for a 1D array but couldn't figure out how to do this for a 2D array.

Also, I'm hoping there's a builtin function (like `sum`) that doesn't require me to specify something myself...

```
set of int: foos = 1..10;

array[foos] of int: assignment;

var bool: any_fun = sum(i in foos) (assignment[i]) > 0;

solve minimize any_fun;

output [show(any_fun)];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the function I was looking for: `exists`. It should work as follows:

```
solve minimize sum(foo in foos) (
  exists(bar in bars) (assignment[foo, bar])
);
```